# Selecting default directory for .fileImporter on SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-fileimporter

Does anybody knows how to define default selected folder for using with `.fileImporter` modifier on SwiftUI?

UIKit `UIDocumentPickerViewController` has the parameter `directoryURL` for this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller.

Is there something similar for SwuifUI `.fileImporter`? If not, what could be the code to implement this with a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, or so?

Comment: Thanks. It’s a general question. I mean: for using it on a iOS/macOs common app.

Comment: Done. You're right, now is more clear.